# How to remove a specific neuron inside Model Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there a way to remove a specific neuron inside a model?

For example, i have a model with a Dense layer with 512 neurons. Is there a way to remove all the neurons that have their indices inside `list_indeces`?
Ofcourse removing a Neuron will affect the next layer and even the one before.

Example:

I have this common model present in multiple papers:

```
data_format = 'channels_last'
    input_shape = [28, 28, 1]
    max_pool = functools.partial(
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D,
        pool_size=(2, 2),
        padding='same',
        data_format=data_format)
    conv2d = functools.partial(
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D,
        kernel_size=5,
        padding='same',
        data_format=data_format,
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        conv2d(filters=32, input_shape=input_shape),
        max_pool(),
        conv2d(filters=64),
        max_pool(),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10 if only_digits else 62),
    ])
    return model
```

Let's say that from the layer `tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu)` i want to remove 100 neurons, basically turning them off.

Ofcourse i will have a new model with the layer `tf.keras.layers.Dense(412, activation=tf.nn.relu)` instead of `tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu)` but this modification should be propagate to the weights of the next layer too, because the connection from the neurons of the dense layer to the next one are deleted too.

Any input on how to do so? I could do this manually by doing something like this:

The model shape is this one if i get it correctly: `[5, 5, 1, 32], [32], [5, 5, 32, 64], [64], [3136, 512], [512], [512, 62], [62]`

So i can do something like this:

1. Generate all the indices i need and same them inside `list_indices`
2. Access the weights of the layer `tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu)`, and create a tensor with all the weights that are inside `list_indices`
3. Assign the new tensor of weights to the layer `tf.keras.layers.Dense(412, activation=tf.nn.relu)` of the submodel

The problem is that i don't know how to get the correct weights of the next layer of weights that corrispond to the indices of the weights i just created and the one that i should assign to the next layer of the submodel. I hope i have exaplained myself clearly.

Thanks,
Leyla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operation is known in the literature as `selective dropout`, there is no actual needing to create every time a different model, you just need to multiply the output of your selected neurons by 0, such that the input of the next layer does not take those activations in account.

Note that if you "turn off" a neuron in the layer `Ln` it does not "turn off" completely any neuron in the layer `Ln+1`, supposing that both are fully-connected layers (dense): each neuron in the `Ln+1` layer is connected to **ALL** the neurons in the previous layer. In other words, removing a neuron in a fully-connected (dense) layer does not affect the dimension of the next one.

You can simply implement this operation with the [`Multiply Layer` (Keras)](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/multiply/). The drawback is that you need to learn how to use the [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/). There are other ways but are more complex than this (eg. custom layer), also functional APIs are very useful and powerful in many aspects, very suggested reading!

Your model would become like this:

```
data_format = 'channels_last'
input_shape = [28, 28, 1]
max_pool = ...
conv2d = ...

# convert a list of indexes to a weight tensor
def make_index_weights(indexes):
    # converting indexes to a list of weights
    indexes = [ float(i not in indexes) for i in range(units) ]
    # converting indexes from list/numpy to tensor
    indexes = tf.convert_to_tensor(indexes)
    # reshaping to the correct format
    indexes = tf.reshape(indexes, (1, units))
    # ensuring it is a float tensor
    indexes = tf.cast(indexes, 'float32')
    return indexes

# layer builder utility
def selective_dropout(units, indexes, **kwargs):
    indexes = make_index_weights(indexes)
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, **kwargs)
    mul = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()
    # return the tensor builder
    return lambda inputs: mul([ dense(inputs), indexes ])

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
conv_1  = conv2d(filters=32, input_shape=input_shape)(input_layer)
maxp_1  = max_pool()(conv_1)
conv_2  = conv2d(filters=64)(maxp_1)
maxp_2  = max_pool()(conv_2)
flat    = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(maxp_2)
sel_drop_1 = selective_dropout(512, INDEXES, activation=tf.nn.relu)(flat)
dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10 if only_digits else 62)(sel_drop_1)
output_layer = dense2
model = tf.keras.models.Model([ input_layer ], [ output_layer ])
return model
```

Now you just need to build up your `INDEXES` list according to the indexes of those neurons you need to remove.

In your case, the tensor would have a shape of `1x512` because there are 512 weights (units/neurons) in the dense layer, so you need to provide as much weights for the indexes. The `selective_dropout` function allows to pass a list of indexes to discard, and automatically will build up the desired tensor.

For example if you want to remove the neurons 1, 10, 12 you just pass the list `[1, 10, 12]` to the function and it will produce a `1x512` tensor with `0.0` at those positions, and `1.0` in all the others.

### EDIT:

As you mentioned you strictly need to reduce the size of the parameters in your model.

Each dense layer is described by the relation `y = Wx + B`, where `W` is the kernel (or weights matrix) and `B` is the bias vector. `W` is a matrix of `INPUTxOUTPUT` dimensions, where `INPUT` is the last layer output shape and `OUTPUT` is the number of neurons/units/weights in the layer; `B` is just a vector of dimension `1xOUTPUT` (but we are not interested in this).

The problem now is that you are dropping `N` neurons in the layer `Ln` and this induce the drop of `NxOUTPUT` weights in the layer `Ln+1`. Let's be pratic with some numbers. In your case (supposing `only_digits` as true) you start with:

`Nx512 -> 512x10 (5120 weights)`

And after dropping 100 neurons (it means a drop of 100*10=1000 weights)

`Nx412 -> 412x10 (4120 weights)`

Now each column of the `W` matrix describe a neuron (as a vector of weights with a dimension equal to the previous layer output dimension, in our case 512 or 412). The rows of the matrix represent instead a single neuron in the previous layer.

The `W[0,0]` indicates the relation between the first neuron of layer `n` and the first of layer `n+1`.

- `W[0,0] -> 1st n, 1st n+1`
- `W[0,1] -> 2nd n, 1st n+1`
- `W[1,0] -> 1st n, 2nd n+1`

And so on. So you could just remove from this matrix all the rows that are related to the neuron indexes you removed: `index 0 -> row 0`.

You can access the `W` matrix as a tensor from the dense layer with `dense.kernel`

Comment: I appreciate your answer. The problem is that i need to use a different scenario, i'm forced to use a submodel with less weights than the original one. So i actually need to take all the correct weights and transfer them to the submodel

Comment: PS: I can't edit the comments above. Even if it was not the answer to my problem, you explained very well and was a good answer if the scenario were different, all that to say that i'm not the one that downvoted your answer.

Comment: Ok so if you are constrained to get a lighter model, you should also reduce the matrix of the second dense by hand. The shape of the second kernel is [`shape=[last_dim, self.units]`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1190), in your case expands to `shape=[512, 10 if only_digits else 62]`. This means that the column-index of the (suppressed) weight in the previous kernel is the row-index in the current kernel

Comment: @Leyla23 don't worry for the downvote, I've edited the answer, check if it matches your conditions in this way

Comment: That's should do the trick! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry if i jump inside the conversation, but this is also a problem i'm facing. Does the same relation apply if i want to have a dropout on the filters of the conv2d layer?

Comment: Hi @Fanto, actually conv2d layer has a different relation with respect of fully-connected layers (`y = W*x + B`, where `*` is the cross-correlation operation). Usually is not a good idea to insert a dropout in a conv2d since the number of weights in the kernel is way lesser of a dense layer. For example, take an image 3x28x28 (channel x width x height). A 3x3x3 kernel has just 27 weights (regardless of the image resolution), comparing it with a fully connected layer with 3 units which has `INPUTx3` weights, that in the image is 7056 weights.

Comment: I get your point, but still, for studying purpose, what is the correlation of the weights of the conv2d layer to the next one? For a dense layer, like you suggested, is `index 0 -> row 0`, but i can't understand the correlation between weights of the conv2d and the dense layer. So that if i reduce the conv2d filters i can find which weights need to be removed from the dense layer to keep doing the dropout.

Comment: @Fanto the fact is that you can't isolate the amount affected by a neuron of the kernel to the next layer, since almost all the output is affected by that neuron. If you change the kernel size, the output dimension will not change (assuming the right amount of padding in the kernel such that it can pass all through the image). If you pass from `Cx5x5 pad=2` kernel to `Cx3x3 pad=0` kernel you obtain the same output shape. Look at first pixel in the output: `OUT[0,0,0] = k[0,0,0] * IN[0,0,0] + k[0,0,1] * IN[0,0,1] + ... + k[C,3,3] * IN[C,3,3]`. If you drop a weight you still have the others